# Is there a way to make a span tag perform a PHP query?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following icon present in my system, which on click, should allow the user to delete a post:

```
<span id='remove' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span>
```

clicking on the icon should then perform a PHP query which will drop the row from the table, removing the post from the database.

But I am unaware and want to discover if making an icon perform an action is possible?

Comment: You can attach an event listener to the `span` to see when it's clicked, and then invoke an AJAX request to run your PHP query and return the results to your page and update what you need with it

Comment: Very common to do this as outlined above. Just need some attribute values from element or it's parent(s) to send to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The process

There are essentially five steps to take :

1) You can send a HTTP request to an url `http://www.example.com/post/15` when you click your `remove` button :

```
$("#remove").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "DELETE",
      url: "http://www.example.com/post/1",
      data: [],
      success: function() {
          console.log("Yey!");
      },
      dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

3) On the server, you could use `.htaccess` to forward all your requests to `index.php`.

4) In `index.php`, you could use eg. `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to know that `post/15` is the final part of your url `http://www.example.com/post/15`. From this, your code in `index.php` should conclude that that you're trying to do something with the `post` that has an `id` with value 15, and from the request type it can conclude that you want to delete it.

5) Once you know that, you can just delete the post with `id` 15 from the database and `echo` whatever response you want to send back to the client.

---

### Some sources to check out

- [How to Use jQuery’s $.ajax() Function](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)
- [A Beginner’s Guide to HTTP and REST](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340)
- [Httpful: The REST Friendly PHP HTTP Client Library](http://phphttpclient.com/)

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is make a button in the same form and hide it by using css, then you could activate this button on clicking the span tag:

Html:

```
<input type="submit" id="#hiddenButton" style="display:none;"/>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#remove").click(function(){
    $("#hiddenButton").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to bind an action to a browser event (such as a 'click'). In your case, look at the onclick event in javascript.

It may be easier to use jQuery:
https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler

Then you will need to use ajax to submit the form to the server (your php script). jQuery provides functionality for this as well:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/